# Determining client's real IP address in VPN connection

Tags: vpn, ip, firefox, geolocation

Is it possible to extract The IP of my PC when I'm connected to a VPN connection and surf internet?

By saying "IP of my PC" I mean the IP address of my system when I'm not connected to the VPN connection.

In general, is it possible for a website to determine whether I'm connected to a VPN connection or not when I'm visiting it? Does VPN connection cause additional data being sent or modify something in http header which is detectable?

Tell you the truth, I'm using VPN to connect to GoogleCode since it is banned for Iranian users. But even through a VPN connection from US, Google finds out that I'm connecting from Iran. So Google can find out about my location whether by determining my real IP address or *maybe* by my browser (Firefox4) when `geo.Enabled` is set to true.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your VPN Endpoint, is your VPN Endpoint in Iran or elsewhere? Google will see your VPN Endpoints IP Address.

Nothing additional is sent in the http header, if you are connecting through VPN. However you might want to checked your routing table to make sure that your data **is** going through the VPN and not through your default route (which may not be the vpn endpoint).

Comment: Thanks. By VPN Endpoint, do you mean VPN Server location?

Comment: yes VPN Server Location

Comment: Then I guess Firefox has burned me! :p Thanks for the info.

Comment: well you could use a different browser which doesn't send geo information, and make sure that its the browser which is the issue.

Comment: Just tested it. Yup! it's FF. Set geo.Enabled to false in about:config if you care...